# Cannot logout when using security-constraints

Tags: security, jsf, primefaces

I've written an application using Glassfish 3.1.2.2 and Primefaces 4.0.   This is really at the start, so there's not much going on.  I have added Form-based security.  When I first did this, I had all of the xhtml pages in the same folder in my WAR file.  I was able to logout by having the following methd in my UserBean

```
public String logout() {
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    session.invalidate();
    return "welcomeRedir";
    }
```

Where my faces-config.xml had the following navigation rule

```
    <navigation-rule>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>welcomeRedir</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/welcome.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Where welcome.xhtml is the original Login page.  And, when I had it defined this way, it worked.  I could login using a JDBC realm and when I clicked the logout button, the page navigated back to the welcome page.

Next, I wanted to add security constraints.  So, I moved the relevant pages (but not the welcome page) to subsdirectories, and added the appropriate security-constraint elements to the web.xml.  And I can still log into those pages.

But, when I click the logout button, nothing happens.  If I look at the network traffic being sent from the browser, it's getting a 403 error as a response.

I've looked and looked, but I can't find anything relevant.  Has anyone gotten this to work when security-constraints are defined?

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- More efficient, in an AJAX environment, to have server side state saving -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- HTML comments become components unless they're stripped -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- PrimeFaces Theme -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>cupertino</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>welcome.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/resmandb</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Protected Pages</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>ApplicationPages</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/protected/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
            <role-name>registeredUser</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>System Admin Pages</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>SysAdminPages</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/sysadmin/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>authentication-realm</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/welcome.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/welcome.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <description>A System Admin of ResMan</description>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <description>A Registered User of ResMan</description>
        <role-name>registeredUser</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<faces-config version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd">
    <application>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>messages</base-name>
            <var>msg</var>
        </resource-bundle>
    </application>
    <navigation-rule>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>welcome</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/welcome.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
    <navigation-rule>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>welcomeRedir</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/welcome.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect/>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
    <navigation-rule>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>reservations</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/protected/reservations.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
</faces-config>
```

Comment: how about posting your latest faces-config.xml

Comment: Added the faces-config

Comment: what is your logout button pointing to right now ?

Comment: Sorry, added web.xml before... now added faces-config.xml

Comment: And logout button is calling #{User.logout} which is the method I've got at the top of the question... it should return welcomeRedir.  But, it's almost like the container is not letting it get that far... that the request is getting 403'd before it gets to the Faces Servlet

Comment: Hmmm, I'm thinking this is less the faces-config, and more the web.xml config around groups...

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, it's nothing to do with the faces configuration and more about how my glassfish-web.xml defined its security-role-mapping elements.  The values in the  elements didn't match the groups contained within my JDBC Realm (ie, the names of the groups in my database tables).   Once I defined these correctly, the logout works.

In truth, until I did this, none of the AJAX requests from Primefaces were being accepted.  It wasn't a logout issue, it was a general interaction issue.